# How to disable operator associativity in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I have a few rules for an expression:

```
e:
  e '*' e |
  e '+' e |
  e '<' e |
  '2';
```

I can specify the associativity of the '+' operator, using `<assoc=right>` for ex., but how can I specify that expressions like `2 < 2 < 2` should be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Rather late in answering this, but,...

The best way to handle seems to be to split your expression into two bits, a boolean expression, and a numeric expression

```
exp:
    numeric |
    boolean

boolean:
    numeric '<' numeric;

numeric:
    numeric '*' numeric |
    numeric '+' numeric |
    2;
```

This will allow things like `1 + 2 < 3` but not `1 < 2 < 3`.